# How to integrate filemanager in tinyMCE successfully?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using tinyMCE for my project and I want to integrate filemanager plugin to it also to mention I am working on localhost(xampp). Structure of my folders for both plugin and upload directory:
`xampp/htdocs/tutorials/js/tinymce/plugins/filemanager` and
`xampp/htdocs/tutorials/js/tinymce/images`

```
$base_url="http://localhost/tutorials"; //url base of site if you want only relative url leave empty
$upload_dir = './js/tinymce/images/'; // path from base_url to upload base dir
$current_path = '../../../../images/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload files folder
```

But when I click on filemanager button in tinymce editor the filemanager 
pop up shows an error

> There is an error! The root folder not exist.

Comment: try to define the upload_dir with out any ''.". It might be that the param gets concatenated

Comment: @Thariama thanks but it didn't work

Comment: sorry, got no other idea here

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this comment and the paths you provided, you should only back up two levels, not four? Also, are you sure you should end it with `/`?

```
$current_path = '../../images/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload files folder
```